# Getting CORS error when sending a POST request to Cloud Function API despite granting permissions - Firebase integration

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have created a Cloud Function using 2nd generation and wrote the following code in its Code section:

```
import functions_framework
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, auth

# Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
cred = credentials.ApplicationDefault()
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

# Function to verify user authentication
@functions_framework.http
def verify_user_token(request):
    # Get the ID token from the request headers
    id_token = request.headers.get('Authorization', '').split('Bearer ')[1]

    try:
        # Verify the user token
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)

        # Get the user ID from the decoded token
        user_id = decoded_token['uid']

        return upload_file_to_dataflow(request, user_id)
    except Exception as ex:
        return "Invalid or expired token. Please sign in again."

# Function to upload the file to Cloud Dataflow
def upload_file_to_dataflow(request, user_id):
    return f"User authenticated. User ID: {user_id}"
```

and when I try to send POST request to this Cloud Function API, I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-analyticsplatform-392414.cloudfunctions.net/upload-data' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I tried to grant permissions to `allUsers` as `Cloud Functions Invoker` but still all in vain. I am still getting the same error.

Can somebody guide me what's wrong am I doing?